# i am unable to upload multiple images in database

Tags: php

i want to upload multiple images using single input. i have two database table say user table and images table. i want to upload all images in image table and data like user name ,email etc in user table. my problem is that i have successfully upload all data in user table but unable to upload images in image table. i am getting any error message but still images is not been upload in image table.. please help me out.. i am getting stuck on it for three days..

this is my view

```
<input type="file" class="input" name="Image[]" multiple accept="image/*" />
```

this is my php code.. i am inserting user information in assgnmentUser table and images in UploadImagesLog can any body please tell me whats the issue in uploading multiple images...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO eOPS.assgnmentUser (
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            Email,
            PostCode,
            CreatedBY,
            CreatedDate,
            IsActive

          )VALUES
              ('".$FirstName."',
              '". $LastName."',
              '". $EmailAddress."',
              '". $postCode."',
              '". $CreatedBy."',
              '". $CreatedDate."',
              0)    
              ";

        mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        // Count total files
        $countfiles = count($_FILES['Image']['name']);
        $lastUserId = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
        // Looping all files
      for($i=0; $i<$countfiles; $i++){

          $filename = $_FILES['Image']['name'][$i];

          $tmpname = file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'][$i]);

          $dir = "/var/www/orangehrm/admin/images";

          $dirfilename = $dir ."/". $filename;

          // Upload file
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'][$i] , $dirfilename)){
            $sql="INSERT INTO eOPS.UploadImagesLog (
              User_ID,
              ImageName,
              ImagePath,
              CreatedBY,
              CreatedDate,

            )VALUES
                ('".$lastUserId."',
                '". $filename."',
                '". $dir."',
                '". $CreatedBy."',
                '". $CreatedDate."'
                )   
                ";
              //  print_r($sql); exit(); 
                 mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

                }


            }

        header("Location: ".$GLOBALS["BrowserURLStart"]."/admin/eOps/AssignmentTask-13/ListingFormImg.php");
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injections, you should consider using prepared statements

Comment: sure.. can you suggest any solution to my problem ?

Comment: does your form tag contain ` enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Have you checked that `$countfiles` is non-zero?

Comment: @TahaPaksu yes i have enctype attribute included in my form..

Comment: @Nick yes i have checked that $countfiles is non zero

Comment: Do you use linux, and if you do, do you have write permission on that folder?

Comment: @TahaPaksum no i am not using the linux, i have solved it. actualy there is lit mistake in my insert query for upload images..anyway thanks for  your help..